# How to make bidimensional arrays with a List<T>?

Tags: winforms, list, c++-cli

**I am using** 
`System::Collection::Generics::List`

Say I have a `List<String^> example;` 
I am able to get the 0th element using `example[0].`

Currently i'm trying to do the following:

```
List<List<T^>^> test;
```

But doing: `test[0][0]` doesn't seem to work at all, like it's not designed for bi-dimensional arrays. Could someone know what am i doing wrong?

This is Windows Forms and i'm forced to use managed structures.

Comment: Just to make sure: You know that you are not using C++?

Comment: I know, it's cli c++

Comment: test[0][0] is correct syntax.  You probably did not initialize the list correctly.  Don't forget that you have to create a List for each element in the outer List.  Copy/paste the compile error or exception if you still have trouble.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: -

```
        List<String^>^ normalList = gcnew List<String^>();

        List<List<String^>^>^ TwoDList = gcnew List<List<String^>^>();

        TwoDList->Add(gcnew List<String^>());
        TwoDList->Add(gcnew List<String^>());

        TwoDList[0]->Add("First List - First Entry");
        TwoDList[0]->Add("First List - Second Entry");
        TwoDList[0]->Add("First List - Third Entry");

        TwoDList[1]->Add("Second List - First Entry");
        TwoDList[1]->Add("Second List - Second Entry");

        String^ sTest = gcnew String(TwoDList[0][1]);

        Trace::WriteLine(sTest);
```

My output window data was: -

First List - Second Entry